# XCode - UIWebView Detect Video Playing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

Is there a way to detect if a video is playing in a UIWebView in a normal class. I am aware of this code where the orientation can change if a video is playing (in the AppDelegate), but am unsure how to implement a code similar to this in my ViewController class:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    id presentedViewController = [window.rootViewController presentedViewController];
    NSString *className = presentedViewController ? NSStringFromClass([presentedViewController class]) : nil;
    if (window && [className isEqualToString:@"AVFullScreenViewController"] && [presentedViewController isBeingDismissed] == NO) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;        
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }}
```